# OpenShift Rollback based on image tag or on image digest?

Tags: docker, openshift

I just took over a project, where obviously someone decided to deploy :latest docker image tags to OpenShift via the deployment pipeline.
We are currently trying to find out if this might lead to issues during a rollback issued by OpenShift.

So let's say we have a statefulset and if we do a rolling deployment and the health check fails on the first pod. On which basis does OpenShift start the "rolled back" pod - on the Digest of the previous image or on the image tag?

If it would be the image tag, the rollback probably wouldn't succeed because :latest already contains the misfunctioning image.

It's an OpenShift 3.6 btw. (if relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer your question is that rollback revert an application back to a previous revision based on Digest of the previous image.